# why does my Firefox redirect to Mozilla update page on www.science20.com url?

Tags: firefox

I can open www.science20.com url normally with Chrome; but if using Firefox, even with javascript and auto redirects turned off, it magically redirects to http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/update/ . Otherwise Firefox works fine, i.e. I have not yet discovered any other such weird urls.

Can't say it's a big problem, but I am quite curious as to why this could be happening.

Answer (score 3):

The entry in the [Places database](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_Places_database) responsible for this URL may be damaged, such that the page stored under the name `www.science20.com` in the database in fact points to the Firefox update page.

Try typing `www.science20.com` in the address bar, select the link in the drop-down box from the address bar, then type <kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete the entry from your browsing history.  Then try accessing the website again.  If this works, the problem is solved; if not, try [creating an empty profile](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) and see if it works.  If not, your system may have a virus that needs to be removed.